# Проблема восстановления пароля wordpress

Tags: wordpress

недели полторы назад, при входе в админку сайта https://tovarivostoka.ru/
вышло сообщение, что нужно сбросить/поменять пароль, при смене пароля(через wp_users) - также не работает вход, пишет - что нужно сбросить пароль, при нажатии на "Забыл пароль" - переходит на главную страницу сайта и все.
проверял в chrome и в opera.
за пару дней до этого -  установил Let’s Encrypt, все работало

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_11441/8-sposobov-ustanovit-parol.html

Comment: решил проблему, скопировав инструкции с главы "Авторизация PHP". зашел в админку(увидел, что пароль не стоит) - создал новую, входи заработал, спасибо p.s не знаю, как пометить ваше комментарий как Решение